# How to use Go Beta/RC version in azure pipeline

Tags: go, azure-pipelines

I want to use a beta or release candiate of Go in the azure pipeline, but the Task "Go tool installer" doesn't work with a version like "1.17rc1".

##### Pipeline

$(go_version) = 1.17rc1

```
steps:
  - task: GoTool@0
    displayName: Install Go tools in version $(go_version)
    inputs:
      version: $(go_version)
```

##### Output

```
2021-07-15T08:01:13.5566938Z ##[section]Starting: Install Go tools in version 1.17rc1
2021-07-15T08:01:13.5573377Z ==============================================================================
2021-07-15T08:01:13.5573650Z Task         : Go tool installer
2021-07-15T08:01:13.5574064Z Description  : Find in cache or download a specific version of Go and add it to the PATH
2021-07-15T08:01:13.5574305Z Version      : 0.180.0
2021-07-15T08:01:13.5574495Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-07-15T08:01:13.5574776Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/go-tool
2021-07-15T08:01:13.5575073Z ==============================================================================
2021-07-15T08:01:13.8414712Z Downloading: https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.17rc1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
2021-07-15T08:01:16.3008064Z Extracting archive
2021-07-15T08:01:16.3027619Z [command]/usr/bin/tar xC /home/vsts/work/_temp/50a79994-bdb5-417d-8374-cd9746166c5f -f /home/vsts/work/_temp/d2be4a68-029c-4393-8492-5b804e41857e
2021-07-15T08:01:19.0933870Z Caching tool: go null x64
2021-07-15T08:01:19.1004014Z ##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of null
2021-07-15T08:01:19.1090132Z ##[section]Finishing: Install Go tools in version 1.17rc1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an issue with the task itself. It throws here:

```yaml
async function run() {
    try {
        let version = tl.getInput('version', true).trim();
        await getGo(version);
        telemetry.emitTelemetry('TaskHub', 'GoToolV0', { version });
    }
    catch (error) {
        tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, error);
    }
}
```

And this is kind of strange as I don't see here any logic preventing from putting there `1.17rc1`. I created and issue for this on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/15044)